Is there a reason why I am getting a null-related error in this code
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

fun checkNameOccurrence(people: List<Person>): Map<String, Int>{
    // The map has a key that represents a name and a value of how many times that name is repeated
    val namesMap: MutableMap<String, Int> = mutableMapOf()
    for(person in people){
        if(person.name in namesMap.keys){
            namesMap[person.name] += 1
        }
        namesMap[person.name] = 1
    }
    return namesMap
}

I don't understand the reason for the null-related error in the code. Isn't that code block only meant to run if the key is found in the map, how is there still be a null error.
I'm partly new to Kotlin and I've only worked on python before (there weren't any issues with null values in python)

The compiler is just not smart enough to understand namesMap[person.name] can't be null in this case. You can use !! or getValue() to enforce non-null value:
namesMap[person.name] = namesMap.getValue(person.name) + 1

However, there are much shorter and cleaner alternatives to your code. First, we don't have to check if the value exists, but just default to 0:
namesMap[person.name] = namesMap.getOrDefault(person.name, 0) + 1

This replaces the whole if-else block, not only the single line from the original code.
Even better, the whole function could be replaced with:
people.groupingBy { it.name }.eachCount()

It groups people by the name and counts how many times each name existed in the list.
